# Dont work "remove" in Doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Why I can't delete entry in database using Doctrine 2 Entity manager?
I have next controller and entity with whom I have a problem.
I get in controller object form entity manager and i can't delete this object. Why?

```
// /Controller/Controller.php
/**
 * Handler delete checkbox
 * @Route("/administrator/services/delete/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 0}, name="service_delete")
 * @Template()
 */
public function serviceDeleteAction(Request $request, $id){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $repoServices = $em->getRepository(CoworkingService::class);

    $services = $repoServices->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
    $em->remove($services);
    $em->persist($services);
    $em->flush();

    return [];//$this->redirectToRoute('administrator');
}

// /Entity/CoworkingService.php
class CoworkingService
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SentviBundle\Entity\Language")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $language;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="common_identifier", type="text")
 */
private $commonIdentifier;
```

Thanks!

Comment: try removing `$em->persist($services);`

Comment: @Matteo, this awesome. It work for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Matteo’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306869/dont-work-remove-in-doctrine2#comment71768987_42306869) has already solved the issue, but let me explain what has happened.

You’re executing 3 entity manager operations:

```
$em->remove($services);
$em->persist($services);
$em->flush();
```

You must know that, before you call `$em->flush()`, all operations are registered in a service called the “unit of work” (UOW).

The UOW keeps track of all modifications in your entities (including adding/deleting entities), and only applies them to the database when you call `flush()`.

When calling `$em->remove($services)`, you told the UOW that you want to delete the entity. However, when calling `$em->persist($services)` directly afterwards, you told the UOW that you want to create (or, effectively: keep) the entity. (Note that, in Doctrine, “persist” doesn’t mean that a connection is made to the database, but instead, you pass an entity to the EM/UOW to calculate the modifications.)

So, in conclusion, the `persist` operation cancelled the `remove` out, and, at that point, `flush` had nothing to do.

For more details on the entity lifecycle and EM states see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html